# R studio not showing plots, base R, no error message

Tags: r, plot, filepath

I'm struggling to ask this question as I am unsure as how to ask it.

I have been writing a program to cycle through files on my computer to create charts from cdv's present within, and then saving the charts to a new directory. This code works well, however when I try to plot within Rstudio itself, the charts do not show in the plots viewer.

A simplified section of the code that works is as follows:

```
  x <- c(6,  7,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)

  y <- c(1600, 1500, 1500, 1300, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000)

  save_path <- file.path(paste0("/File/Directory/", paste("File name", ".pdf", sep = "")))

  pdf(file = save_path)

  plot(x, y)      

  dev.off()
```

However, after running this code I am no longer able to use the simple command within the console:

```
  x <- c(6,  7,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)

  y <- c(1600, 1500, 1500, 1300, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000)

  plot(x, y)
```

There is no error message, and the console shows that the program executed the code, however no plot appears in the plot window.

Each time I run

```
dev.off
```

I get the following in the console:

```
> dev.off()
pdf 
  7
```

With each time I execute the command, the number underneath the pdf increases by one.

Comment: Seem like you didn't make sure to close the pdf device each time when one of your plots was finished. You need to run dev.off() a few more times.

Comment: You may switch off all devices at once using `graphics.off()`. Then try again.

Comment: I run dev.off() after each plot is created in the loop, so directly after the the chart is saved, but yes running dev.off() in a loop eventually gave an error that it couldn't shut down a null device, and now all sorted. Cheers!